# How to create a function connect socket io in factory angular js?

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I'm creating a factory's socket in angular js, however `on` & `emit` function as out of connection's localhost:5793. I mean `var socket = io.connect();` & `socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5793');` are 2 diffirent connection. Do right?. How to 2 socket io are the same variable ( connection )?

```
    var App = angular.module("App", [

    ]);

    App.factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        return {
            connect: function() {
                socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5793');
            },
            on: function(eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, callback);
            },
            emit: function(eventName, data) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line, you create new socket connection - although I'm not entirely sure since you didn't pass any URL

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

then with the following code, you overwrite the variable `socket`and lose the reference to the previously open socket

```
connect: function() {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5793');
},
```

so bottom line the variable socket holds reference to only one connection not two